# Excel VBA Combo box clear

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I am using excel 2010.

I want to clear the content of a combo box in my sheet(clear to blank like when it's not selected), but I don't know how to select and clear. I tried to select a combo box like this:

```
Sheet1.ComboBox1.Clear
```

But no 'ComboBox' is under the Sheet1 object. The only to select my combo box is use this:

```
Sheet1.Shapes("Drop Down 24")
```

I don't know how to select and clear the content, can anyone help me?

Comment: did you try `recording a macro` while doing this manually?

Comment: Like @ScottHoltzman suggested, recording a macro of your intended action and then looking at the code Excel created is a good way to learn how to code in VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Drop Down 24")).Select
With Selection
    .ListFillRange = ""
End With
```

Comment: Thanks. Now all the list options are gone. But I want to keep the original list options. Is there a way to make the combo box clear, and show the options when click the drop down?

Comment: not sure to understand... do you want the combobox to be filled or emptied ? or filled/emptied depending on a certain event? If so I wouldn't recommend using the activex using controls that are not veru flexible, but rather a userform where you can fully take control of all the shapes

Comment: Activex controls have the same functionality regardless of if they are on a sheet or userform. The difference is that it is more intuitive how to access them on a userform.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you actually want to make the displayed value of your control blank. In that case, for a [Drop Down Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196004.aspx), as you indicated you would do this:

```
Sheet1.Shapes("Drop Down 2").OLEFormat.Object.Value = 0
```

Where 0 indicates which element from the list is selected I.E. none.

If that doesn't work, then you're probably actually dealing with a ComboBox in which case you want to use this:

```
Sheet1.Shapes("Drop Down 2").OLEFormat.Object.Object.Value = ""
```

Note this code was created and tested in Excel 2003 (what I have on this machine) so the path to reaching the actual object might vary slightly on Excel 2010.)

Answer (score 1):

As an autentic programmer I would rather prefer this way. That don't depends on excel "range memory selection" on the sheet.

```
Set oCombo = Sheets("SheetName").Shapes("cmbComboName").ControlFormat
For I = oCombo.ListCount To 1 Step -1
    oCombo.RemoveItem (I)
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

To reset a Drop Down List to a blank cell but still maintaining the list for future use.

Create a  Macro to clear the cells. During recording simply select the cell and select "clear contents". This will set the selection to a blank cell but still keeps the drop down list in place.

It would look like this for example.

```
Range("H3").Select
Selection.ClearContents
```